# Fourier sine inverse for two functions multiplied

Tags: fourier-transform

If the fourier sine transform of $f(x)$ is
$$F_s(f(x))=\int_0^\infty f(x) \sin(\omega x) \, dx$$
and the fourier sine inverse of a function is $$f(x)=\frac 2 \pi \int_0^\infty F(\omega) \sin(\omega x) \, d\omega$$

I want to know whether the convolution and multiplication rules of Fourier Transform can be applied using Fourier sine and cosine also ..
I mean if I want the ***inverse Fourier sine*** of $$F(\omega)G(\omega)$$
then will it be  $$f(t)*g(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)g(x-\tau) \, d\tau$$ ??

Comment: Not exactly the convolution. I couldn't find a reference in Wikipedia, but see equation 3.2.31 in this PDF: http://dsp-book.narod.ru/TAH/ch03.pdf